Dealing with overflow and underflow in integer and floating-point multiplication
I'm dealing with a problem where I have a huge collection of 16-bit signed integers. I must multiply each by a constant factor of type double and promote convert it back to the integer type. I need to check for both overflow and underflow, and in case of such occurrences, the result should be set to the integer limit, and a warning should be printed informing the user about the problem.
I came up with a solution using C but didn't like it too much. I'm also questioning the efficiency of the check. Basically, I'm looking for a "best practice" approach.
int16_t *sample = malloc(2);

for (unsigned long i = 1; fread(sample, 2, 1, inputf); i++)
{
    // Check overflow/underflow
    if (fabs(INT16_MAX / (double) *sample) < fabs(factor))
    {
        if (copysign(1.0, factor) * *sample > 0)
        {
            printf("Overflow in sample #%li\n", i);
            *sample = INT16_MAX;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Underflow in sample #%li\n", i);
            *sample = INT16_MIN;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        *sample = (int16_t) (*sample * factor);
    }
    /* Do stuff with sample */
}

free(sample);

I have already considered saturation/wrapping of integers, but according to this question, relying on saturation or wrapping is considered undefined behavior for signed integers. I also came across this question, but gosh.


Edge cases are wrong. sample[0] * factor is only a problem when the truncated product is outside int16_t range.  fabs(INT16_MAX / (double) *sample) < fabs(factor) nearly does that, but not quite.  2) No need to repeatedly perform fabs(factor). Once is enough. 3) unsigned long range may exceed size_t range 4) When |factor| <= 1.0, no check needed.  5) INT16_MAX / (double) *sample risk division by 0 6) what range is factor constrained to?


Does your factor need to be double or could you convert it to a fixed-point value? Or is float also sufficient? If you need to do this for lots of values, does your CPU support SIMD (e.g. SSE or AVX)?

Re “promote”: FYI, this is not a promotion. Converting from double to an integer type is just a conversion. A promotion is a conversion to a “greater” type that does not change the value because all values in the source type are representable in the destination type. The C standard’s integer promotions convert to a greater rank, and the default argument conversions also convert float to double. It is distinctive that these default promotions do not change the value. Converting from double to an integer type can change the value and is not a promotion.

Your checks are not correct because int16_t is not symmetric. It is two’s complement, so INT16_MIN is −32,768, and INT16_MAX is +32,767. Also, since conversion from floating-point to integer truncates, there is no overflow unless the value is outside the open interval (−32,769, +32,768). If you want to use a smaller range than that as the bounds limit to report a warning, you should edit the question to state that.

@chux-ReinstateMonica 1) I didn't understand very well. I only used INT16_MAX for both limits for simplicity, since INT16_MIN is just one more in absolute value. Are you saying I could just check sample[0] * factor > INT16_MAX and the same for the lower limit? 2) Indeed. 3) I didn't give much thought to the counter. I used unsigned long because I don't know how many 16-bit samples there are, but since it's coming from a file, it can't be that much. 4) Yes. 5) Right. I didn't think of it. 6) factor is a user input coming from command line argument and treated as double.

@chtz factor is coming from a user input. In my case, it can be treated as a fixed-point value or stored in a float without problem. I'm using double for no specific reason other than it's the data type that fabs() and copysign() take in hehe. But I don't want to be much restrictive about this.

@EricPostpischil You're right. My snippet is sure quite naive. I didn't think about the fact that I could just perform the multiplication and check the double result. The fabs() and such are there because my head was in a state where I was fixed in perform the multiplication inside the assignment (stupidity). I'm using a 16-bit integer in this case, but what about larger integers?

16-Bit Integer
The range for int16_t is [−32,768, +32,767], since it is a 16-bit two’s complement type (and these limits are specified in C 2018 7.20.2.1 1). When a floating-point value is converted to an integer type, it is truncated (6.3.1.4 1), so all values inside the open interval (−32,769, +32,768) have defined results (do not overflow), and values outside that overflow (the C standard does not define the behavior).
The C standard’s requirements for float are such that all integers from −32,769 to +32,768 can be represented. Per 5.2.4.2.2 14, the spacing between representable numbers in a neighborhood of 1 is at most 10− 5, so the spacing in the neighborhood of 32,769 is at most 32,769•10−5 = .32769. Further, 5.2.4.2.2 13 tells us this is within the range of the float format (at least 1037). So integers up to 32,769 in magnitude are representable. The float values are a subset of the double values per 6.2.5 10.
Therefore, we can perform the desired scaling, test, and conversion with:
float t = *sample * factor;
if (t <= INT16_MIN - 1.f)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Warning, underflow in sample #%lu.\n", i);
    *sample = INT16_MIN;
}
else if (INT16_MAX + 1.f <= t)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Warning, overflow in sample #%lu.\n", i);
    *sample = INT16_MAX;
}
else
    *sample = t;

The above uses float since it suffices for range, but double may be used if more precision is desired in the representation of factor or the product.
Wider Integer Types
The IEEE-754 binary64 format commonly used for double is sufficient, as its 53-bit significand ensures integers up to 253 can be represented.
However, the C standard alone does not guarantee this. It only guarantees spacing of 10−9 in the neighborhood of 1 and a 32-bit int may have values up to 2,147,483,647, this is insufficient to guarantee the test may be performed in the same way as above. For general portable conversion of floating-point values to integer types, this answer provides safe code.

To speed along performance, code does not need to do any floating-point math in the loop.
Find the limits before the loop
For simplicity, let us first assume factor > 0.
#define CONVERT16(sample, factor)  (int16_t)((sample) * (factor)))
#define CONVERT32(sample, factor)  (int32_t)((sample) * (factor)))

// Range of allowable samples, inclusive.
int sample_min = INT16_MIN;
int sample_max = INT16_MAX;
if (factor > 1.0) {
  // Rough approximation 
  sample_min = (int16_t) (INT16_MIN / factor);
  sample_max = (int16_t) (INT16_MAX / factor);
  // Refine
  // This step may not be needed - will have to ponder this more.
  // Yet since it is before the loop, the cost is minor.
  if (sample_min > INT16_MIN && CONVERT32(sample_min-1, factor) >= INT16_MIN) {
    sample_min--;
  if (sample_max < INT16_MAX && CONVERT32(sample_max+1, factor) <= INT16_MAX) {
    sample_max--;
  }
}
else {
  // TBD code for factor <= 0.0
}

// Now in the loop simply perform integer compares.
for (unsigned long i = 1; fread(sample, 2, 1, inputf); i++) {
  if (*sample < sample_min) {
    printf("Underflow in sample #%li\n", i);
    *sample = INT16_MIN;
  } else if (*sample > sample_max) {
    printf("Overflow in sample #%li\n", i);
    *sample = INT16_MAX;
  }
  *sample = CONVERT16(*sample, factor);
  /* Do stuff with sample */
}

Left OP to code for when factor <= 0.0.  Note that if (factor < -1.0) { is amiss as 1.0*INT16_MIN is out of int16_t range.

I do not see what you are thinking here. The loop contains CONVERT16(*sample, factor), which multiplies by factor, so it does contain floating-point arithmetic. At most, you are replacing floating-point compares with integer compares and avoiding the multiplication in some overflow cases. Besides that, you want an else on *sample = CONVERT16(*sample, factor);, sample_max-- should be ++, and I question whether the calculations of sample_min and sample_max are correct but have deferred analysis since you indicate you are pondering them more.

Are there any chances of INT16_MIN / factor equaling INT16_MIN (same for INT16_MAX / factor) assuming factor > 1.0? If not, sample_min > INT16_MIN and sample_max < INT16_MAX can be removed. Indeed this approach skips some multiplications and the conditions now are integer comparisons, but it's a bit harder to understand (the increment/decrement part... it can be honed, though). If CONVERT32() can be removed, it's really straightforward to generalize to other integer sizes. Hoping others can suggest modifications/improvements!
